# Cleaning gems from older gem version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I recently upgraded my distro (Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04), and I guess either on the upgrade or on the regular `sudo update/upgrade` calls `gem` was upgraded and I currently have the `2.7.6` version. I barely use Ruby lately, but just now I had to run a `jekyll/bundle` command which returned me that it had a bad interpreter (it was looking for `ruby2.3` and it's currently installed on the `2.5` version).

My next step would be updating the `jekyll` and `bundle` gems (so they update the interpreter version), but to my surprise they aren't listed when I run `gem list`. They were obviously installed since there's a `/usr/local/bin/jekyll` executable and a `/usr/local/bin/bundle` one as well. But I think when `gem` was upgraded it started checking gems on a different folder (`/var/lib/gems/2.5.0` I'm guessing) but `jekyll/bundle` apparently are in `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0`. I'd be fine just installing `jekyll/bundle` on the 2.5.0 version, but is there a way to remove all gem files from the older version since they are useless now?

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to use a ruby version manager like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage different ruby versions installed on your system.

If you just want to remove the gems from your disk, you can find the location of each gem with the command `bundle show $gem_name` and delete the parent directory to delete all of them. You may need to delete the `Gemfile.lock` as well to reset the locked gem versions.

Comment: I'll probably learn and install `rvm` once I clear things up. I hosted Jekyll on Github, so I'm guessing the `bundle` gems are not installed locally. But anyways, I can't run `bundle` because I only have the 2.3.0 version here. I can install the 2.5.0, but I was wondering if there's a `gem` command to clear all the gems from older Ruby versions. `gem list` doesn't even show them right now.

Comment: You can use `gem cleanup` command to remove old versions of gems but it removes the old versions for the current ruby version you use. You can just remove the content from `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0`  to remove all the gems for Ruby version 2.3.0.

Comment: I think manually removing seems to be the only option, at least apparently the only external folder where gem files are added is the EXECUTABLE_PATH (mine is `/usr/local/bin`). So I think I have to remove `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0` and any executable inside `/usr/local/bin` that belongs to one of those gems.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I recommend:

1. Use `rbenv` for multiple Ruby version management, no customizations needed

   - a ruby installer plugin is now included with rbenv
   - it also handles ruby executable shims automatically, don't need to `rbenv rehash` anymore
   - it loads really fast (`rvm` has a noticable load time on shell startup)
2. Use bundler to dynamically resolve gems at runtime (options below)

   - it's fast enough anyways
   - don't need a special gem solution, bundler comes included /w Ruby now

Options to invoke bundler dynamically (I recommend the last one):

1. use `bundle exec` in front of every ruby executable

   - variant: create `alias be='bundle exec'`
2. create `bundle binstubs <LIST GEM EXECUTABLES YOU WANT>` for each project

   - use `bin/` in front of every ruby executable to call the binstubs
3. do #2 and then set up [`.git/safe`](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-safe)

   - lets you manually allow PATH lookups to the `bin/` folder while in that project root
   - don't need to type `bin/` anymore

Now multiple gem versions will all be installed into the same Ruby version bucket, and you let bundler dynamically add the right versions to the load path before every startup.

Removing a Ruby version will also mean removing all the gems (and versions of those gems) installed for that Ruby version as well.

Comment: I used to prefer `rvm` because it was (and still is) a single more self-complete solution that also has gemsets for stricter isolation.

Comment: I upvoted both answers, but they don't quite solve my problem. I just want to clean up the gems that were installed when my system had `ruby 2.3`. Ruby and gem were updated in a system upgrade without cleaning up those. I thought there might be a command to remove those obsolete gems but apparently there's not..

Comment: "gems that were installed when my system had ruby 2.3" -> unless you kept a log of what was installed in that time, there's nothing keeping track of this. If you mean "uninstall everything that's not currently being used", `bundler clean` can do so by checking against a particular `Gemfile`. You could also just completely uninstall everything first, and then reinstall only what you need using the solutions we've provided.

Comment: How could I completely uninstall everything then? Currently `gem` can only see the gems inside `/var/lib/gems/2.5.0` missing the ones in `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0`. I can make it see the latter by adding `GEM_PATH=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0` to the env but I'm having trouble uninstalling them, particularly when it tries to remove the executable. I'm guessing purging `gem` will remove the program but leave the gems behind right?

Comment: Load the ruby environment you want to clean up first, then `bundle clean` with an empty Gemfile, or `gem list`/`gem info` and uninstall everything listed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank both answers. I upvoted them because even though they're not a direct solution to my problem they give good directions to prevent it.

**NOTE: These are the steps I took, which doesn't mean they are the correct way, so don't take more as a reference than a guide.**

Here's what I did to clean up those old Ruby version gems:

- First I needed to add an environment variable for `gem` to be able to find those obsolete gems, by running `GEM_PATH=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0`.
- Then it's possible to get the contents and specification of the gems with `gem contents name_of_gem` and `gem specification name_of_gem`.
- I individually uninstalled those gems that were obsolete with `sudo GEM_PATH=/var/lib/gems/2.3.0 gem uninstall -i /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 name_of_gem`. In my case I did a `sudo` install, so I needed `sudo` which also required me to set the environment variable again because of `sudo`'s security policy. Also, I needed to manually set the install directory for some reason.
- Some gems will have executables, and the uninstall will ask if you want to remove it. I wasn't able to get the `gem uninstall` to remove it because it claimed I didn't have write permission to `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/bin` (which is weird because the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` gem environment variable was `/usr/local/bin`). I asked `gem` not to remove the executables, wrote down their names and removed them manually from the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` folder. You can also use `which gem_executable_name` to find out where it's located.

After uninstalling all the gems I believe it's safe to remove the `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0` folder and its contents. Running `gem contents` on all of them only returned me files on this folder so I believe the only external files were the script/executables that were added to `/usr/local/bin`.